# XML parsing - grouping attributes into nsdictionary with KissXML and XPath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, xpath, kissxml

my attempted goal is to parse this xml doc https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx and eventually get it into core data.

but the snippet i'm having trouble with is

```
<rowset name="requiredSkills" key="typeID" columns="typeID,skillLevel">
          <row typeID="13279" skillLevel="3" />
          <row typeID="3402" skillLevel="4" />
        </rowset>
```

the problem i'm having is trying to figure out how to keep the typeID and skillLevel together to save in an nsdictionary.

So the goal is to put each `<row typeID="13279" skillLevel="3" />`  into its own object.

the main code i'm using is

```
-(void)parseXMLFromBundle
{
NSError *error;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SkillTree" ofType:@"xml"];

DDXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] options:0 error:&error];

//main array with everything
NSArray *xmlItems = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//result" error:&error];
//go through it to extract each thing
for (DDXMLElement *itemElement in xmlItems)
{
self.typeArray = [itemElement nodesForXPath:@"//@typeName" error:&error];

self.requiredIDArray = [itemElement nodesForXPath:@"//row[@typeID]/@typeID" error:&error];
DLog(@"required SkillID: %@",self.requiredIDArray);
```

}

The typeName works fine, each object I want only has 1 name, but it can have multiple typeIDs so I am trying to group these values into 1 object so i can import it all into core data eventually.
I know with the typeIDs are also just being all dumped into an array. I am just lost as to how to get stuff better separated by elemental row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be much easier if you used NSXMLParser. On each opening of a row tag you would create a new object to represent it. You also get a dictionary of all attributes at this time and so you'd set the properties of the new row object instance with that.

Comment: That's what I figured, I was just banging at this with the wrong tool, thanks